# base64 image not displaying in image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

hi i am using a jquery image up-loader in which upon selecting an image i get its base64 code.

```
function readImage(input) {
    if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
            $('#img').show().attr( "src", e.target.result );
            $('#base').text( e.target.result );
        };
        FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
    }
}
$("#upload").change(function(){
    readImage( this );
});
```

i am storing the base64 encode into my database and retrieving it on another page i am getting the following data from my table

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIABAMAAAAGVsnJAAAAIVBMVEUAAAB fX1 fX1 fX1 fX1 fX1 fX1 fX1 fX1 fX1 fX1I2PRsAAAACnRSTlMAF/ClME Kb9vEsIrXWQAACWpJREFUeNrs3T1rVEEUBuBzs1 JlbGImkpREW6lVrqVhBBCKhESIZWCIqTSgEZSKSrCVordVrrxY/P SouEJG7uzH7k3rBz3vf5CYe9Z87MOTNrIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiMo755fWdty931pfnjU/25EGOI73vby4akWzjPk75 IIlBtlGF4X2OUKw0kXQ/nPzrnEPUTcemWsrOYboef4RZO8wgi9uM0Gri5HsvzKXWh2MqO8yApdzjKz32txZyDGG3jNzZiEHmCPQyjGm3lNzpNHB2PqOSqKsjQns akHtjGR2 bEKib02VyoYWJ3zYF6BxPrP7T0HSYA2jRQAwDij DgAyD CLYBgPgjqOHM7ljKujizfUvYVZTgmyUr66AE/XT3BKsoxSdLVD1HKXqpLoWPUZJblqQGSpPm2cgSSnPTEnSQAYizwBWU6IMl57gGIK0F5lCqr5aaLk4g3BHU8B  TeEuSvbXklJH6dJaCQ/XQN6VsI3S7VlCWqhASmMjSzhCuSE4UQVyVoPHRQBpKbCJSvy2VHRQib4looUjnOvAJVTkuqWhjRMIa6EGBrAdjs6iMu8tBVuozB9LQIYKpVAMNlGhFOZnBxdBuoVwMAWwJYEsR4V6058EmhjAlgROpQC2JLCLAkyn4zkq1bMp10IBpi3xHIoQdUnXULFfNt22UISoFOqgGMvBYB1BHE3SGkJIugMzqNw1m2abCCFpj7QRQnI0jHNgU6yBCIaz8SbCKI4E5hBCshtYxDn4adNrE0Ec6 AWwii2Qx2EMWyHMkT57481EENQCDQRQ1AI1BBDsCGeRZz7MYkLOBc/bFqtIc79wfAmYghKwV1E e8PthHl/0yoizj3V hyRLnvEGeIYNgM0Aegjjj33TH6ADQQ5X8/rACgGE0AWhjC 6AUfQCaiPJ/JqYAoJgCwBIA iSoAKAYTQDoK0EFAMVoAkB/HkAfAEMUwahkB1H Z2ToGyP0rbEtxBDMydG3x kHJBYxhPdh4RlE b81NIc49/Py9IOS9KOy9MPS9OPysVqYoRIeNijofkwwVgpSFILDxsXdD4vr4qSuzlqOIPdzoro rwcU9ISGHlEJLgMsi0BoGaBZBPSUlh5To39Or4FTqHKgntQsyIJUOTDQHWLoCgVrQaY6MHQ0znEkrsfV9by /mAh L4 0ev6 pOVgSTAlwKKrg24vyjwj70zeXUiCMJ4jU4UPAUjbifFfU4qLpiTG6i3EHHBkwvicnI/eFJRwdxcEMlJJwpaf6XPjDGTWXq6J/Owa7763QR5PNvpqq  qu6umpds/4SkyRMA8gKKEiFcEtQHF/XJTX10VZ/dnecByBygT2/r4 v6/H76BF37z8pVTAwiTAeWSgFMETAPg7ghcNYlBeqJFqlBVBU4YyOeF7ZIGHFjxMJyYMJpbozdJJEwwv4AiE5jfwBEYYT9ARCd50Z4TVIJRqgaYMY2boD3JJg YhWQZj2YE5ZnyEuyh2QTjpaMgGJT4IweL8UhEs8jXoJ9JJLgRvoPY67Nr7QE2CxHDzyKTzaSCeIHC8JazOdwNRO7L3BNPmXyyRsSwYXcWP/9BmbCOsmKCKCXt/HDca0AcJJSPJeSFNZHBeMsnVENBTAoGLuJvdeF/4TPJLss7gEwTV KMLpf0srZ7LgC8Q1Ks1bKsOjVTA6f03NWgIVawvNU0DOUMZuj2v//NBSijjuRaaxvy8g6/j00DR7G3p6cC/plQjahM7bMfwMiMojpia aeFhVy4eH2YJdJ7M/V4hHsM5itvVixBXER3M/V8jMbDA2V3MJnYqPYNfA6uf6uAmGdvV8cHFkiH5Hu/nSUohRttbQ1DAugfmfT eFDI6HIwdPK7j8gXMcuN11cNR  SaJhwZNX8Smyyei1F/6ePtUSWklxC1eZ6xqiwnOXrry7NaxO08vnS2LaeFYSr gb/I1aofs4L6UjtE2s7VbcwWCR1J6hlWDAHtrrUBwU0zPZMjc/AoEN8V0zdYxN78CwU05p8j6XM3kJDkR9uV0zteyDZMBOdDpy5mgtm19xUfImjMRF BpUbSNbXlr esGdyWNz7gMQv16SBZsGYsaoDrPLhyvjIXhY1kjdKGr329egvBxJGyI8rR7y t4l0oIHo kjdHWmob9eexJwRoE526N5M3RnuZ6xB fLvzi4ZUTkcRJ6qXGofe/ 7hiBqxYAie vJI6Sr2VPeAluePVMLTgYWovPoD/ AkEY/YC54rA07OR8k5V9tkTJuSG79cFSblg6Bp7ww9ywts7EmTdrrCRPWInWdE EeQmhtqZA50zof8XZ4q4bLPDnjEgCzwwAjLIPWHvVQh0u2zQz1typN2z85y9w0INemKFZRB5zYQnTojjQ4xtLITdimKfzoT/RagU8KoOcquIPL87W8ge8HQHGPYAxg4w7QGAHFC1B9pcCFbuAZQdULoHUHZA6R6A2QHmPSDqgXWf6wHPzEAna9D3d5REvMTkoRdk4Qu1syPo4Au12Q218UYRCiHTYTIQGVgqBnGSYHkibOdQgO2oAFASNCdCb9/PSZDxGo/HlWBZRYgWAnJBAC0EZIMAXAjIBQG0EJANAnghIBME8ELAagaB7SyCb5QCqxBY7XLAazdsTkwLAHkBxZ4AiCFeao7j2IGFxiCeDFpFKRSwGLo0p5VnhP7PGaI1LIYdNKfV47E2D5S2fjasiF UgBoD01EQUAcuaEFEHbioBcHssLwtBlcLZytimL64oUsOMBxmGhcD8wOzviCkEE6JYUQzIGUJ4CaBJA0AJ4F0GsBqCmXbQ6CVwGI10Mr7EuxvVADrimX6Y7hZcJYHAS3xjDWO1hbMNAiBs A0DyJnwb95ELUW/FsPohqCCS wZQDzN2wZMBUCuMXwv4IYsS22Ou0xFgitAKyDpkoIWQcxPyBoHcR8EFsHNauENrBAvtIKiJ3hGd xhWAiBQHnoxYnpWANsT9MsJXwVAvjOoKJK4g5ITenS6DTITMG2KUA8wMCnBNPc10XQBdAY4BmAYD7w8qIu1oLqB8AnQaua2OkQbaxON7TlJY9Lfj/HiFcLywTxg oYXqiViA RI3TufeKhbD/84AURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURVEURfndHhyQAAAAAAj6/7ofoQIAAAAAAAAAAPwEGcG4SMHdcSkAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
```

now it want to show the image in my image tag for that i am writing the following code

```
$('#img').show().attr( "src", convert[0].profile_picture);
```

i am getting the code in convert[0].profile_picture variable.

but the image is not getting displayed. the screenshot of which is 
[screenshot of image tag in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqNA6.png)

i referred to other questions and tried using

```
    var data = btoa(convert[0].profile_picture);
 $('#img').show().attr( "src", data );
```

but the result is same. in btoa do i have to remove data:image/png;base64, and then try converting it? i tried some online base64 to image conversion like

[i used this link to try and covert base64 to image](https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder)

but there i am getting Invalid mime type: application/octet-stream error.

what am i doing wrong?

Update:- the problem occurs when i am getting data from database and using it in src attribute of an image tag and not just after selecting the image and previewing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your base64 data is invalid. Spaces are not allowed.

Comment: This. And the code shared in the question seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld53q8f8/

Comment: @Intervalia thank you for responding so quickly. i used

var str = convert[0].profile_picture.replace(/ +/g, "");
                    $('#img').show().attr( "src", str );

to remove all white spaces between words. but still image is not displaying.

Comment: If that worked then you need to ask yourself **Why does my data have spaces.** It might be worth it to find out why and then remove the spaces at the source so you don't have to remove them every time your code runs.

Comment: @blex thanks for checking my question out but in fiddle image is being displayed just after the image is selected which is the preview of the image. the real problem occurs when i am getting data from the database and using it in the src attribute of the image. the data from database is mentioned in the question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

thank you very much @Intervalia, i reviewed my code and found that javascript while sending data was replacing few characters. so i rectified my code and used

```
var image=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("base").innerHTML);
```

and then sent image to database. and when i retrieved it, it started displaying.

thanks a lot again.